# How to search for all associations in a relationship tree in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm having a problem. I have tables that relate:

**internal_clients->subsidiaries->departments->job_titles->users**

I also have their respective models.

**My doubt is:**

How do I get all the data associated with users from the top of the tree (internal_clients)
?

I'm trying to follow the Laravel documentation using hasManyThrough.

However, in the documentation it explains only how to do it in a chain of three tables. They teach how to place an intermediate table (model) as the second parameter of the hasManyThrough method (BaseClasse::class, IntermediaryClass::class).

However, in my case that has several tables between users and internal_clients, how would I do this? What would be the intermediate table?

I would like to make a query that returns the user's internal_client, subsidiary, department and jobTitle (associated with users).

I'm trying to do it this way:

**Model InternalClient**

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, InternalClient::class);
}
```

**Controller UserController**

```
public function allRelations($internalClientId)
{
     $internalClient = InternalClient::find($internalClientId);
       
      $users = $internalClient->users;

      return response()->json($users, 201);
}
```

- The InternalClient id arrives at the controller above.

When I access the **route**, the **error below is returned:**

[image]

**In short:** I would like to know if there is a way to get all the data (from all tables that are in this hierarchical tree) that are associated with the User.

I couldn't find an answer on the Stackoverflow PT-BR.

Thank you!

Comment: has many through works for only one level of nesting, you should use something like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Comment: You can include nested relationships like `InternalClient::with('subsidiaries.departments.jobTitles.users')->get()`, but each of those would be independent relationships on each model, and not a single `hasManyThrough()` (which also doesn't work as noted above). You'd still have to do iteration, like `foreach($clients as $client) { foreach($client->subsidiaries as $sub) { ... } }`